# how to specify URL in filters pagePath core reporting api V3

Tags: google-analytics-api

I am building a web app that pulls data through the Core Reporting Api v3 from Google. I am using the client PHP library offered by Google. 
I am currently trying to specify a page and retrieve its pageviews for a time range. Every other seems to be working okay except for the fact that if a specfy a filter with `ga:pagePath==http://link/uri` then I get `0` all the time no matter the time range.

I think the problem is got to do with the setting of value for this pagePath. I want to have spearate data for the desktop version of the site and the smartphone version `denoted by s. subdomain`

Can anyone hint me on some tips and or tricks to use to get the required data?

Example URL:
    http://domain.com/user/profile/id/1
    http://s.domain.com/user/profile/id/1

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Start off by seeing if you can get values by just comparing a substring of your path.  Use the =@ operator instead of ==

Answer (score 18, accepted):

for the the default implementation of Google Analytics, ga:pagePath doesn't include the scheme or hostname so in your case you'd actually want to filter using ga:hostname and ga:pagePath together.

I suggest you use the [Query Explorer](http://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/explorer/) to build your queries and get familiar with what will work. You can also use this tool to at least get a sense for what type of data the ga:pagePath and ga:hostname dimensions return before trying to filter on them. Finally, once you have the query you want, you can easily get the exact Core Reporting API query by clicking on the Query URI button.

Also check out the [Combining Filters](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/reference#filters) section of GA API docs.

So if you want filter on ga:pagepath for domain.com and s.domain.com separately you could do something like

filters=ga:pagePath==/user/profile/id/1;ga:hostname==domain.com
filters=ga:pagePath==/user/profile/id/1;ga:hostname==s.domain.com

Comment: You can also use the Google API explorer to test your queries https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer